# apache/mysql generate too many request on amazon centos

Tags: mysql, linux, apache, amazon-ec2, centos

My issue is, my website open too many connections in mysql server this is hanged my website and also generate many requests on apache. i have installed the apache module mod-evasive and mod-security i have also empty the iptables rules basically i am using amazon ec2 so it gives security ip i have blocked all outbound and inbound i have opened only 443,80 and ssh 22 port only but still when i take netstat it shows

netstat -anp |grep 'tcp\|udp' | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n

```
  4 --0.0.0.0

  4 ---119.159.195.199

 25 ---54.69.254.252

374 ---
```

on above my question is why my server 374 apache connection on ::1:80 how can block this or reduce this

mysql connection stat are

+-------------------+-------+
| Variable_name     | Value |
+-------------------+-------+

| Connections       | 5208  |

| Threads_cached    | 0     |

| Threads_connected | 54    |

| Threads_created   | 5207  |

| Threads_running   | 54    |

+-------------------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

my second question is why my sql connections is increasing.

Please any one help me i will really appreciated.

Comment: The most likely answer is your server is too small and your code quality is not high enough to scale properly.  As your traffic increases, the load goes up, causing requests to finish more slowly, causing requests to back up, causing apache to spawn more children.  This is a very broad question and looking for a solution in server configuration is unlikely to take you down the right path.  What are all of these processes *doing*?  What pages are involved? What database queries are running *right now*?  You are the only one who can see these things... not us.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you are right i can see those things but my question is how can we prevent the ddos internal attack basically currently it attack through localhost. I have checked all the things cron job or script there is no evidence to get that thing. Can you more explain on that.